# Elastic Search.NET - Handling multiple inner_hits with different names

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, elasticsearch, nest

We are using ElasticSearch.Net API.

We have multiple inner_hits in our query. We get the expected response with all inner hits but we need to get inner_hits in our class from reponse.

Can anyone guide us on this?

Below is our query -

```
GET ai/_Users/_search
{
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "must": [
            {
               "nested": {
                  "path": "roles.permissions",
                  "query": {
                     "bool": {
                        "must": [
                           {
                              "match": {
                                 "roles.permissions.pname": "p1_name"
                              }
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  },
                  "inner_hits": {
                     "name": "Permission1"
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "nested": {
                  "path": "roles.permissions",
                  "query": {
                     "bool": {
                        "must": [
                           {
                              "match": {
                                 "roles.permissions.pname": "p2_name"
                              }
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  },
                  "inner_hits": {
                     "name": "Permission2"
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "_source": "false"
}
```

We have below classes created to handle Elastic response -

```
public class sharedData
{
    public Nullable<int> total { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> successful { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> failed { get; set; }
}

public class HitsData
{
    public string _index { get; set; }
    public string _type { get; set; }
    public string _id { get; set; }
    public double _score { get; set; }
    public Object _source { get; set; }
    public inner_hits inner_hits { get; set; }
}
public class inner_hits
{
    public Permission1 Permission1 { get; set; }
}

public class Permission1
{
    public Nullable<int> took { get; set; }
    public bool timed_out { get; set; }
    public sharedData _shards { get; set; }
    public Hits hits { get; set; }
    public Aggregations aggregations { get; set; }
}


public class Hits
{
    public int total { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> max_score { get; set; }
    public HitsData[] hits { get; set; }
}

public class Aggregations
{
    public ChildObjectAggregations childObjectAggregations { get; set; }
}

public class ChildObjectAggregations
{
    public int doc_count { get; set; }
}

public class ResultElasticData
{
    public Nullable<int> took { get; set; }
    public bool timed_out { get; set; }
    public sharedData _shards { get; set; }
    public Hits hits { get; set; }
    public Aggregations aggregations { get; set; }
}
```

Below is our code to get inner hits from Elastic response -

```
ElasticsearchResponse<ResultElasticData> x = objElasticsearchClient.Search<ResultElasticData>("ionai", "IACM.AI.BOD.Application_Users", sJSONQuery);
            if (x.Response != null && x.Success == true && x.HttpStatusCode == 200)
            {
                foreach (HitsData hit in x.Response.hits.hits)
                {
                    foreach (HitsData innerhit in hit.inner_hits.Permission1.hits.hits)
                    {
                        innerhit._source.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Here the problem is, we can only get inner hits for inner hits with name 'Permission1'. It is because we created class for only Permission1.

So our question is if we have multiple inner hits with different names then how to get all inner hits? We can not create the classes for inner hits upfront as we don't know how many inner_hits will be there.

Any guidance is highly appreciated.

Thanks.